# Can a team admin create a distribution provisioning profile? Or just the team agent?

Tags: ios-provisioning

From what I see on the forums, it looks like only the **team agent** can see the Provisioning -> Distribution tab in the iOS provisioning portal.

BUT... the documentation clearly states otherwise, so I'm confused. As **team admin**, should I be able to see the distribution tab? And therefore be able to create an ad-hoc profile? Or is the documentation wrong, and only team agents can do this?

Here's the excerpt from this [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/ProvisioningPortal_Recipes/CreatingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html) which clearly states:

> Only team agents and **admins** can create a Distribution Provisioning Profile

But yet here is a screenshot of the distribution tab which I **can't** see as team admin (it's not there at all):

[image]

Here's the proof that I am a team admin:

[image]

Am I going mad? Should I raise a ticket with Apple on this, or is the documentation just incorrect?

Or perhaps there's some step that I need to do before I can see this tab?

Hope someone knows the answer!

cheers,
Stretch

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause of your issue is but I can assure you an admin can create a distribution profile.  I work for a small company of which the owner is the agent.  I created our last projects prov profiles and I am an admin.

Comment: hmm, that is what I thought... ok there must be something up - time to speak to apple I guess? @Kibitz503 There was nothing you had to do setup-wise to be able to see this tab then?

Comment: Nope my boss just set me up as an admin.  I am also an admin on one of our frequent clients accounts and I make their profiles too.  For me it is the same view as my personal provisioning portal account.

Comment: hey whoever that was - why the downvote? this was a legitimate question as the documentation was not representing what I was seeing. It's courtesy on SO to give reasons for a downvote.

Comment: We're seeing this same issue. I am a Team Admin, and I can see the Distribution tab, but a co-worker who is also a Team Admin can't see it. Neither of us is the Team Agent.

Comment: @KristopherJohnson - Raise it as a bug.. it took them a couple of weeks, but they did fix it for me in the end.

Comment: We were able to "fix" it ourselves. The developer who couldn't access distribution profiles was a Team Admin for the iOS Developer Program, but was only a Member of the company's Mac Developer Program. When we made him a Team Admin for Mac as well, then he was able to access iOS distribution provisioning profiles.  Don't know if that is a bug in how the Provisioning Portal determines privileges, or if changing his Mac privileges caused something to get reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged a ticket with Apple - and they have acknowledged that this is a bug, and they are looking into it.

UPDATE: Apple did fix the problem after a few weeks. I had a few phone calls from them to keep me updated on it's progress - was quite impressed by that.

Answer (score 0):

This is my work's account.  I am an Admin for it but not the Agent.  It is the same as the screen I see on my personal account of which I am the Agent.

[image: My Works account to which I am an Admin but not Agent.]

Comment: Thanks, this confirms that I think there is something wrong at the Apple end - I've sent an email to their provisioning team.

Comment: Here's the answer from Apple: "Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Program Support regarding the iOS Provisioning Portal.

Please know that only Team Agent has an eligibility to create an iOS Distribution Certificate and Distribution Provisioning Profiles." They must be wrong though, if you can see this tab! I will probe them some more :)

Comment: That's odd news.  I logged in to the Dev Center to probe some more and found that I was unable to see the dev tab for one client.  For that client I am a Member and not an Admin or Agent.  For Every account that I have Admin or Agent status for I can see this tab.  I would be very interested to hear what you find out :)

Comment: I raised this with Apple - it is indeed a bug, and they are looking into it. For me, I've had to beg and borrow the team agent's login so that I can sort out the provisioning profiles.