# Code Sign error when building using jenkins xcode build plugin

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, jenkins

I get the following error when using the XCodeBuild plugin of jenkins:

> Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any
>   valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains

Update: I am able to xcodebuild from terminal and build in xcode to simulator and to device however not when running it in jenkins - jenkins seems to have some different 'shared' osx user because its home folder is in users/shared?

Comment: What does your build command look like in jenkins?

Comment: please try following link which may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614657/code-signing-error-running-xcodebuild-in-jenkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe build machine you are using does not have the private key that matches the certificate that is inside the Provisional profile.

Comment: I am using my local machine but it seems to create a 'shared' user - xcodebuild works fine from command line and in xcode but not when jenkins calls it

Comment: Jenkins can use a script for additional options, one of them is profiles.  Make sure the profile is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

By default when Jenkins is installed it runs as a daemon as opposed to a process under your current user. As such it does not have access to any of your credentials which are needed to code sign your app.

Instead of running Jenkins as a daemon, you should just launch it like a normal process. It would probably looks like something like this:

```
java -jar /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war
```

Comment: Alternatively see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827874/missing-certificates-and-keys-in-the-keychain-while-using-jenkins-hudson-as-cont/9482707

Answer (score 1):

I also run jenkins as a daemon and code signing works fine using the plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Keychains+and+Provisioning+Profiles+Plugin

(Jenkins 2.19.1 with Xcode 8)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the build machine, but the user doing the build. He's missing those certificate and private key. You need to manually add a login.keychain especially for him.